# How can I work around needing to apply a type before it's defined?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I walked into an interesting problem.  Here's my types

```
export interface QuestionPrimative {
    question    : string;
    id          : string;
    name        : string;
    formctrl?   : string;
    formgrp?    : string;
    lowExtreme? : string;
    hiExtreme?  : string;
    template    : string;
}

export interface Answer {
    answer      : string;
    id          : string;
    trigger?    : string;
    formctrl?   : string;
}

export interface QuestionBase extends QuestionPrimative {
    answers?: Answer[];
}

export interface MicroQuestions {
    activate?   : string;
    questions?  : QuestionBase[];  // I actually want this to be Question[]
}

export interface Question extends QuestionBase {
    micros? : MicroQuestions[];
}
```

I'm loading this into an `Angular 2 Component` I created for my questionnaires to automatically handle any style of question I throw at it. To give a better example for what I'm doing and why I shaped everything this way here's a commented version of the entire model

```
//The data when it iterates into Component
question    : string;           // the question to be asked
id          : string;           // id attribute for HTML
name        : string;           // name attribute for HTML
formctrl?   : string;           // if element will be a form control
formgrp?    : string;           // if element will be a form group
template    : string;           // matches *ngIf on appropriate chunk of HTML
answers?    : Answer[];         // available answers if multiple choice
lowExtreme? : string;           // low extreme if question involves rating
hiExtreme?  : string;           // hi extreme for rating
micros?     : MicroQuestions[]; // if more questions are available

//if answers are available.....
answer      : string;           // the answer
id          : string;           // id attribute for HTML
trigger?    : string;           // used to trigger another tier of questions
formctrl?   : string;           // if element needs to be a form control

//if there is another tier of questions ......
activate?   : string;           // matches with the 'trigger' in the answer to know to load
questions?  : QuestionBase[];   // the next tier of questions(which I want to have micros)
```

Does anybody know how I can type this to work in a loop the way it needs to?

Comment: Well, you replace `questions?  : QuestionBase[];  // I actually want this to be Question[]` by `questions?  : Question[];`.

Comment: oh wow, idk what I did wrong then because I got an error before and something familiar resonated from the Tour of Heros tutorial where they emphasized creating your types in an order where they'd be already defined when used otherwise the data model wouldn't work. so I thought I had walked into that, but it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `QuestionBase` with `Question` and it works just fine:

```
export interface QuestionPrimative {
  question: string;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  formctrl?: string;
  formgrp?: string;
  lowExtreme?: string;
  hiExtreme?: string;
  template: string;
}

export interface Answer {
  answer: string;
  id: string;
  trigger?: string;
  formctrl?: string;
}

export interface QuestionBase extends QuestionPrimative {
  answers?: Answer[];
}

export interface MicroQuestions {
  activate?: string;
  questions?: Question[];  // Works
}

export interface Question extends QuestionBase {
  micros?: MicroQuestions[];
}
```